# Play store in-app billing exception

Tags: android

I am seeing null exception when trying to implement in-app purchase v3 in my app. Following is my code:

```
    mServiceConn = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            mService = null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            mService = IInAppBillingService.Stub.asInterface(service);
        }
    };

    MainActivity.this.bindService(new Intent(
            "com.android.vending.billing.InAppBillingService.BIND"),
            mServiceConn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

    try {
System.out.println("mService " + mService);
        Bundle buyIntentBundle = mService
                .getBuyIntent(
                        3,
                        getPackageName(),
                        "android.test.purchases",
                        "inapp",
                        "aaa");
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = buyIntentBundle
                .getParcelable("BUY_INTENT");
        startIntentSenderForResult(pendingIntent.getIntentSender(), 1001,
                new Intent(), Integer.valueOf(0), Integer.valueOf(0),
                Integer.valueOf(0));
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SendIntentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The exception I see is that service is null. The sysout I have placed in code is printing null. All of the above code is part of onCreate method of my activity. Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

Anyone struggling with this one, simply move the following code to onServiceConnected method. We shouldn't try access service, until it is bound.

```
    try {
System.out.println("mService " + mService);
        Bundle buyIntentBundle = mService
                .getBuyIntent(
                        3,
                        getPackageName(),
                        "android.test.purchases",
                        "inapp",
                        "aaa");
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = buyIntentBundle
                .getParcelable("BUY_INTENT");
        startIntentSenderForResult(pendingIntent.getIntentSender(), 1001,
                new Intent(), Integer.valueOf(0), Integer.valueOf(0),
                Integer.valueOf(0));
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SendIntentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```